# Is there any difference between Left hand limit and left hand derivative?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, continuity

I am kinda a stuck at this part. Do tell me about the RHL and RHD as well. It may sound a bit stupid but how are they used differently?

Answer (score 0):

If the left-hand limit equals the right-hand limit at $a,$ the function is continuous at $a.$

If the left-hand and right-hand limits, exist but are not equal, the function will have a jump-discontinuity.

If the left-hand derivative equals the right-hand derivative at $a,$ (and the function is continuous) then the function is differentiable at $a.$

If the left-hand and right-hand derivatives, exist but are not equal, the derivative will have a jump-discontinuity.  And, the graph of the function will have a kink in it.

Some examples include $f(x) = |x|$ or $f(x) = x^{\frac 23}.$  Both are continuous functions and have a kink at $x=0$